# ubuntun 14.04 not Detect Bluetooth Dongle

Tags: bluetooth

my ubuntu not detect bluetooth ..

this is lsusb out :

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1058:1110 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 046d:c01d Logitech, Inc. MX510 Optical Mouse
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 046d:c318 Logitech, Inc. Illuminated Keyboard
Bus 007 Device 007: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

this is dmesg out :

```
[ 5525.548037] usb 7-1: new full-speed USB device number 6 using uhci_hcd
[ 5525.797782] usb 7-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0a12, idProduct=0001
[ 5525.797789] usb 7-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 5525.797793] usb 7-1: Product: Bluetooth V2.0 Dongle
[ 5525.797796] usb 7-1: Manufacturer: Bluetooth v2.0
[ 5722.020090] usb 7-1: USB disconnect, device number 6
[ 5728.876037] usb 7-1: new full-speed USB device number 7 using uhci_hcd
[ 5729.125912] usb 7-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0a12, idProduct=0001
[ 5729.125918] usb 7-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 5729.125922] usb 7-1: Product: Bluetooth V2.0 Dongle
[ 5729.125925] usb 7-1: Manufacturer: Bluetooth v2.0
```

this is lsmod out :

```
Module                  Size  Used by
btusb                  27580  0 
rfcomm                 53664  12 
bnep                   18895  2 
bluetooth             342208  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
nouveau               969577  3 
joydev                 17101  0 
hid_generic            12492  0 
usbhid                 47070  0 
ses                    13075  0 
hid                    87604  2 hid_generic,usbhid
mxm_wmi                12893  1 nouveau
enclosure              14827  1 ses
wmi                    18673  2 mxm_wmi,nouveau
snd_hda_codec_realtek    59259  1 
video                  18903  1 nouveau
ttm                    72725  1 nouveau
snd_hda_intel          42730  5 
drm_kms_helper         48868  1 nouveau
drm                   244037  5 ttm,drm_kms_helper,nouveau
snd_hda_codec         164067  2 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13272  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                85501  3 snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_page_alloc         14230  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
i2c_algo_bit           13197  1 nouveau
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
gpio_ich               13229  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
coretemp               13195  0 
snd_rawmidi            25135  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                55383  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
serio_raw              13230  0 
snd_seq_device         14137  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              28584  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
lpc_ich                16864  0 
snd                    60939  19 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
ppdev                  17391  0 
soundcore              12600  1 snd
parport_pc             31981  1 
lp                     13299  0 
mac_hid                13037  0 
parport                40836  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
usb_storage            48417  0 
psmouse                91357  0 
r8169                  61562  0 
mii                    13654  1 r8169
```

and this is `hcitool dev` out :

```
Devices:
```

in lightdm bluetooth is ON

please help

Answer (score -1):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1314621

Upgrade to at least kernel version 3.14.1.
See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds for details.

Comment: I would not advise using the mainline kernel for this.

Comment: I agree. I've upgraded the kernel as well as `nvidia-*` drivers, and I'm getting strange slowdowns in one certain program… GHC if anyone's curious—but everything else seems to be normal. Trying to figure out what's going on.

<br>
  
Downvoting my own answer. D:  
  
@bodhi.zazen Would you have a better suggestion?

Comment: Apparently I can't down-vote my own post. Nor can I figure out how to do paragraphs like a proper civilised person.